# Approximate average customer lifetime using churn

Tags: sequences-and-series

Average customer lifetime can be approximated using formula:

$1/Churn$ (churn is a real number in interval $(0;1)$

The same can be achieved using more complex formula:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-Churn)^{(n-1)}$

[Wolphram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%281-0.0205%29%5E%28n-1%29%2C%20n%3D1%20to%20infinite) calculates for $Churn = 0.0205$ sum of $48.7805$. This matches $1/0.0205 = 48.7805$

Does it mean that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-Churn)^{(n-1)} = 1/Churn$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have a [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) of how long customers stay.  Your sum is a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)  Using the sum of a geometric series you can prove the equality you want.